# Spark SQL - Get Column Names of a Hive Table in a String

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get the column names of a Hive table in a comma separated String. This is what I'm doing

```
val colNameDF = spark.sql("show columns in hive_table")
val colNameStr = colNameDF.select("col_name").collect.mkString(", ")
```

And the output I get is

```
res0: String = [col_1], [col_2], [col_3]
```

But what I want is `col_1, col_2, col_3`. I can remove `[` and `]` from the String, but I'm curious as to whether we can get the column names without the brackets in the first place.

**Edit:** The column names in the Hive table don't contain [ ]

Comment: what is the printSchema for the dataframe ?

Comment: @dumitru col_name : string (nullable = false)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the columns ??

Comment: Your approach unnecessarily triggering spark job using ```.collect``` function to fetch meta details, check my approach will not trigger any job it will give you required meta detials.. some one downvoted without knowing how it works..

Comment: @Srinivas Yes, I tried your approach and it works too. And we should get a feature to give comment while downvoting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `show columns`,  Try below approach as it is faster than yours.

```
val colNameDF = spark.sql("select * from hive_table").limit(0)
```

**Or**

```
val colNameDF = spark.table("hive_table").limit(0)
```

```
val colNameStr = colNameDF.columns.mkString(", ")
```

Answer (score 3):

The collect returns to you an array of `Row` which is particularly represented internally as array of values, so you need to trick it like this:

```
val colNameDF = spark.sql("show columns in hive_table")
val colNameStr = colNameDF.select("col_name").collect.map(r=>r.getString(0)).mkString(", ")
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I had one more query, though. I have another dataframe (df2) with same column names as the Hive table, but the columns are in a different sequence. I was trying to get these column names a s String so I could select the columns from `df2` in that sequence. But apparently, df("col_name") takes only one column name and not comma separated columns list

Comment: is this something that helps you `df.select("col_1", "col_2")` ?

Comment: I can use that but it accepts columns, not a String, I think

Comment: it accepts the name of the columns, given as String

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Srinivas' answer above, here is the equivalent Python code.  It is *very* fast:

```
colNameStr = ",".join(spark.table(hive_table).limit(0).columns)
```